# issue about abort http request on angular.js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I try to write an interceptor that controls whether internet connection exists or not. If connection does not exist, it will show a message that "You have not connection" and it aborts the http request,else it will make htt prequest.How can I make this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you should use the following plugin: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information`

code example:

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($rootScope, $cordovaNetwork) {

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    var type = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork()

    var isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline()

    var isOffline = $cordovaNetwork.isOffline()


    // listen for Online event
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){
      var onlineState = networkState;
    })

    // listen for Offline event
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){
      var offlineState = networkState;
    })

  }, false);
});
```

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/network/